# Only show 1 <tr> , show more onClick?

Tags: jquery

Here's what id like to do. I have a table with a bunch of rows. I want only the first 1 to be shown, the rest will be styled with a `display:none`. Theres going to be a link that when click, will remove the `display:none` off of one additional row. Here's what i got so far http://jsfiddle.net/dBdV7/ .

Problems:

1. First of all, it says loadmore is not defined.. why?
2. How do i get the load more link to go away once all the rows are showing?
3. Im nt sure if that `slice` will work properly but it what im trying to do is limit the selected to children to just one .
4. And finally, i manually added the `hide_row` classes, how can jquery automatically add it to all the children of the table onload except the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

To load more than one `tr` (two by two or more...) find the demo in my comment below the answer.

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/dBdV7/29/)*

Thanks to @Lix for the comment: to **ADD/VIEW** the next rows - than just use this jQuery:

```
var curr = 0;
var rowN = $('.main_table tr').length;

$('.main_table tr').eq(curr).siblings().hide();  // no need for CSS

$('a.load_more').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();   
    $('.main_table tr').eq(++curr).show();
});
```

---

**BEFORE:**

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/dBdV7/25/)*

I created a nice script that will allow you to loop!

 That means **if at some point you reach the last `tr` it will bring you back to the 1st one!**

HTML:

```
<table class="main_table">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.....</td></tr>
</table>

<a class="load_more" href="#">Click to load another row</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var curr = 0;                     // set desired starting one (zero based)!
var rowN = $('.main_table tr').length;

$('.main_table tr').eq(curr).siblings().hide(); // hide all but current one

$('a.load_more').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior

    ++curr;
    if(curr===rowN){curr=0;} // reset to 0 at some point

    $('.main_table tr').eq(curr).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: almost perfect, but can i switch to show two on load, and every click shows an additional two ? (i used one for demonstration purposes, in reality itll be more like 20)

Comment: @JonahKatz Sure you can! use `.slice()` : http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/dBdV7/30/ In the demo I added a `var step = 2;    // show two by two` Just change '2' to anything you desire! :) Happy coding!

Comment: @jon - If that's what you wanted then you should have stated so in your post.  Adding that information in a comment is not very polite to the 4 other people who are also trying to help.  Their answers are now only half correct because you have changed your question slightly...

Comment: @Lix I perfectly agree with you, but I'll take it more like: *"..hey bro, thanks for the answer, I have just an offtopic question bla bla bla"* Don't take it personally... ;) +1 to your answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you can use `:not` and `:first` selectors:

```
$('tr:not(:first)').addClass('hide_row') // adds the class to all tr elements except the first one
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dBdV7/23/)

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $('.hide_row:hidden:first').removeClass('hide_row');
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dBdV7/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for you -

Given this markup -

```
​<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="hide"><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class="hide"><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr class="hide"><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr class="hide"><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr class="hide"><td>6</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​
```

The `hide` class simply has a definition of `{ display : none; }`

This line of jQuery will reveal another row each time.

```
$('table tr').not(':visible').filter(':eq(0)').show();
```

I'll go selector by selector, each level specifies one more definition till we find the element that we are looking for.

- `$('table tr')` - These are all of the table rows
- `.not(':visible')` - These are all the "hidden" rows
- `.filter(':eq(0)')` - This is the first result
- `.show()` - Reveals the row

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/VEavW/1/)

---

This of course could be minimized even more into -

`$('table tr:not(:visible):first').show();`

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/VEavW/)

That will achieve the same results - but IMO sometimes its better to be more verbose so that your code becomes more readable...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var current=2;
function loadmore() {
    $('.main_table tr:nth-child('+current+')').show();
    current++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Grrr... I hate when things don't start with a zero index :P `:nth-child` always trips me up!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are defining the loadmore function within `jQuery(function () { ... });` which means it is not visible to the onClick event.  I recommend the following code instead of using the onClick event in the HTML:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.main_table').find(".hide_row").slice(0,1).removeClass('hide_row');
});
```

Using slice instead of the `first` selector allows you to show more than one more row at a time if you want to add that feature. Otherwise, I would use the `first` selector since it makes it apparent to others of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: that's great. And yeah, slice is better because i used one for demonstration purposes. Im loading dynamic data and am going to be changing the amount. One more thing, can you add that onload, all the rows get the class `"hide_row"` except the first n?